# Centos 6.6 can't install couchdb from EPEL repository

Tags: centos, repository, database

The issue is about unavailability of `couchdb` package in EPEL. Has somebody faces the same issue?

```
yum repolist
```

gets

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
repo id                                                                                         repo name                                                                                                                              status
base                                                                                            CentOS-6 - Base                                                                                                                         6,518
epel                                                                                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                                                         11,173
extras                                                                                          CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                                                                          36
updates                                                                                         CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                                                                        550
repolist: 18,277
```

And

```
yum --enablerepo=epel info couchdb
```

gets

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

The repository was grabbed by running

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora-epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

I don't want to install `couchdb` from sources, it requires installing `rebar` build tool for Erlang, which is required.

I spent a lot of time without success.

Answer (score 2):

Despite a lot of different guides found on the web, e.g. [this one](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-couchdb-on-a-centos-linux-vps/) which is not helpful, I also found the [following](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.epel.devel/9734) that states:

> I just did a query of all the packages in EPEL that are currently
>   orphaned and contain vulnerabilies.  I'm wondering if any of them are
>   still useful or if they can be removed from the repos.  Here's the
>   list:

```
couchdb - epel-all
...
```

Comment: According to [this commit](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/couchdb.git/commit/?h=el6&id=a9c7284e855b7b2df7967d70f42f65fb8ee70a14), couchdb was orphaned in EPEL, so it was removed.

Comment: This is a regular occurence, http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/couchdb.git/ lists couchdb as being removed again on 2015-10-28